# What make it possible that child class i.e. RuntimeException is unchecked and Exception is checked?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

What makes it possible to think compiler that `RuntimeException` unchecked though `RuntimeException` also of type `Exception`. But `Exception` is checked exception?

Answer (score 1):

> That is, the checked exception classes are `Throwable` and all its subclasses other than `RuntimeException` and its subclasses and `Error` and its subclasses.
>
> <sup>[JLS 11 > Exceptions > The Kinds of Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1)</sup>

That's the rule and the compiler is aware of it. The fact that the given exception is a subclass of `RuntimeException` (let's say `givenException instanceof RuntimeException`) is enough to the compiler to not treat it as a checked exception.

> The class `RuntimeException` is a direct subclass of `Exception`. `RuntimeException` is the superclass of all the exceptions which may be thrown for many reasons during expression evaluation, but from which recovery may still be possible.
>
> `RuntimeException` and all its subclasses are, collectively, the run-time exception classes.
>
> <sup>[JLS 11 > Exceptions > The Kinds of Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler designates both of `Error` and `RuntimeException` as two special children classes of `Throwable` to indicate the type of exceptions that you cannot anticipate, and thus the compiler cannot force you to handle it at compile time. Any class that extends any of those two children (`Error` and `RuntimeException`) will inherit the same treatment by the compiler.

Generally, you should rely on Runtime exception for the things that you cannot anticipate at runtime such as accessing an array using an index beyond its capacity. Also, your application usually does not recover the runtime exceptions and errors. That is why as a good development practice, you should only rely on them as your default pattern for handling exceptions.